# Rails: How to resume a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think `rake task` is not the keyword here, but I don't know the `correct` keyword for this problem.

```
  articles = Article.all
  articles.each do |article|
    get_share(article)  #use HTTParty, Nokogiri, etc.
    if article.save
      puts "#{article.url}, #{article.share}"
    end
  end
```

I have this script to get the share number of an url from `Facebook`, `Twitter` and other platform. However, sometimes the loop is interrupted, maybe my internet connection is broken, or maybe the parsing in `nokogiri` go wrong, or simply `artilces` are too many.

So, if I run the `task` again, it will **start over from the beginning**, which is really a waste of time.

Is it possible to let it pick up where the loop stoped(the specific `article` in this case), and start the script from there?

I can output `article.id`, and get the article like `articles = Article.where(id > stoped_id)`, but is this a good solution? or if there is any elegant approach for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you're going to have to store, somehow, which articles you've updated.  You could look at the updated_at field of the articles table, but that would include articles that have been updated via the normal operation of your site.

A super simple method is just to read/write a temp file.  eg

```
tempfile = "/tmp/updated_article_ids.txt"
if File.exists?(tempfile)
  @updated_ids = File.readlines(tempfile).collect{|l| l.chomp.to_i}
end
if @updated_ids.blank?
  articles = Article.all
else
  articles = Article.where(["id not in (?)",  @updated_ids]).all
end
articles.each do |article|
  get_share(article)  #use HTTParty, Nokogiri, etc.
  if article.save
    puts "#{article.url}, #{article.share}"
    File.open(tempfile, "a"){|f| puts article.id}
  end
end
```

If you know that you want to start from scratch, delete the tempfile.  Or, you could have a further test in the code to only use tempfile if it's less than a day old or something.

Comment: Addtional question: how can I jump the `article` to next if it went wrong like wrong url or something? And when `timeout` occrus, is resume the task the only way? or can I re-make an `http request` again?

Comment: Wrap it in a begin-rescue block http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_exceptions.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to implement such tasks using some sort of a tool for this. I personally like [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).

If you're not keen on doing something like that, you can always rescue the exception and do logic around that - either save the id as you mentioned, or do some sort of a sleep-retry logic.